# How to add arcgis templates to .NET

Tags: arcobjects

[image]

How can I add ArcGIS 10 templates to my .NET 2013. and is it for free?

Comment: What is the version your VS? what is the version of ArcObject SDK?

Answer (score 1):

If you ArcObjects version is 10, then the maximum version of Visual Studio that supports ArcObjects SDK, is Version 2010. Please refer to [this](http://help.arcgis.com/en/systemrequirements/index.html#//01510000006n000000) page.

Therefore, you should either downgrade your Visual Studio version to 2010 or upgrade your ArcGIS Version to version 10.2.x [Reference](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/system-requirements/10.2/index.html#//01510000006n000000)

The only supported version of .NET framework that works with ArcObject 10.x.x is version 3.5.
This version of .NET is accompanied with the installation DVD of ArcGIS. Make sure to have it installed prior to developing with visual studio.